# How do you keep OS X Terminal from staying open when executing console applications in MonoDevelop?

Tags: macos, console, monodevelop

I am developing a simple Console Application with MonoDevelop on my Mac. Each time I run the application get this dialog with a request to `Press any key to continue...`

How can I have the application run and then close the Terminal window as it does with Windows and Visual Studio?

[image]

Comment: There is a script that MonoDevelop uses to run the application which includes `read -p 'Press any key to continue...' -n1;`. I'm not sure if you're able to change this script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the project's Run options, uncheck "Pause console output". If it's not interactive, you may also want to uncheck "Run on external console".

[image: Project Run options]